# Starting Threads without Stopping them in my Server Socket causes disconnections

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, server

I have a server coded with `Java` using `Eclipse`, I am running `Android Apps` on this server 
my two phones and the server are at the same network .

when I connect from the phones two the server I can see the clients connect to the server
and when a client is disconnected I can see that too.

when I connect from the first client then I make a connection from the second client then the first client automatically disconnect for no reason.
which means I can not make two moves on the server without one of the client disconnect.

maybe the thing is that when a client connect to the server a thread is created (`myThread`) but when the client is disconnected I think the thread (`MyThread`) is never stopped.
I can see that I get to 30 Thread names.

my question is , if the many threads cause the disconnection, how to stop every thread after the client is diconnected?

```
    public Server() {
    // ServerSocket is only opened once !!!

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);

        System.out.println("Waiting on port 6000...");
        boolean connected = true;

        // this method will block until a client will call me
        while (connected) {
            Socket singleClient = serverSocket.accept();
            // add to the list
            ServerThread myThread = new ServerThread(singleClient);
            allClients.add(myThread);
            myThread.start();

        }

        // here we also close the main server socket
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

class ServerThread extends Thread {
    Socket threadSocket;
    String userName;
    boolean isClientConnected;
    InputStream input;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    OutputStream output;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    public ServerThread(Socket s) {
        threadSocket = s;
    }

    public void sendText(String text) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            counter++;
            input = threadSocket.getInputStream();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            output = threadSocket.getOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(output);

            userName = (String) ois.readObject();
            isClientConnected = true;


            while (isClientConnected) {

                String singleText;

                singleText = (String) ois.readObject();

                oos.flush();
                    for (ServerThread t : allClients)
                        if (t.isAlive())
                            t.sendText(singleText);


            }
            // close all resources (streams and sockets)
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            threadSocket.close();
            counter--;

            System.out
                    .println("disconnected : lost connection - connections: "
                            + counter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            counter--;
            isClientConnected = false;

            System.out.println("Quit App : lost connection - connections: "
                    + counter);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide client code, log output / exceptions.

Comment: Surely its due to the client code. One of the clients in 'allClients' has terminated the connection. And the new client might be trying to write to it.

Comment: i figured it out before,  i just removed the `userName = (String) ois.readObject();` before the loop and it worked fine .. tHANK YOU ALL

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out before,  i just removed the `userName = (String) ois.readObject();` before the loop and it worked fine .. tHANK YOU ALL
                    – amjad